# Issue in cakephp when execute certain MSSQL stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

We have developed our app in CakePHP running with MYSQL and this is working fine. PHP version is 5.4.16, Apache 2.4.4, latest XAMP. CakePHP version: 2.3.0

We already have similar Database in MSSQL also. Now we want to run our app with this MSSQL also.

We are using php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll for MSSQL driver for this. Its sql server 2005.

The issue is that when I run certain sql server stored procedures, cakephp runs nothing. I can see in the SQL profiler that syntax of the stored procedure call is fine and all the parameters are correct. I can also see in profiler that this stored proc is running absolutely fine in SQL server. But cakephp does not show anything.

Corresponding MySql routines are working fine and cakephp returning the correct data.

This is the php code followed by the stored procedures.

```
    $getCoulmnsInfo =$this->Maintable->query('exec GetColumns_Information 0');          

    print_r($getCoulmnsInfo); // This prints nothing, $getCoulmnsInfo is empty
```

Corresponding SQL server stored proc is as

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetColumns_Information]
    @GroupOverride midsys_boolean AS
    IF ( @GroupOverride = 1 )
    BEGIN SELECT columns_id, columns_columntypesid, columns_columnname,    
    columns_usercolumnname, 1 FROM ColumnsTable ORDER BY columns_id RETURN END

    SELECT columns_id, columns_columntypesid, columns_columnname,         
    columns_usercolumnname, columns_columnsettings
    FROM ColumnsTable
    ORDER BY columns_id
```

Now, If modify the above to as below then it works fine and returns the proper results. Basically I removed the few lines in middle.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetColumns_Information]
    @GroupOverride midsys_boolean AS

    SELECT columns_id, columns_columntypesid, columns_columnname,         
    columns_usercolumnname, columns_columnsettings
    FROM ColumnsTable
    ORDER BY columns_id
```

Another example of stored proc which is not working.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MainStatusesFlow_Next]
    @MainID int AS
    DECLARE @MainStatusesID int

    SELECT @MainStatusesID = main_mainstatusesid
    FROM MainTable
    WHERE main_id = @MainID

    IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM MainStatusesTable MainStatuses INNER JOIN         
    MainStatusesFlowTable MainStatusesFlow ON MainStatuses.mainstatuses_id =         
    MainStatusesFlow.mainstatusesflow_nextstatusid WHERE         
    MainStatusesFlow.mainstatusesflow_statusid = 10 )
    BEGIN SELECT MainStatuses.mainstatuses_name FROM MainStatusesTable MainStatuses         
    INNER JOIN MainStatusesFlowTable MainStatusesFlow ON MainStatuses.mainstatuses_id =         
    MainStatusesFlow.mainstatusesflow_nextstatusid WHERE         
    MainStatusesFlow.mainstatusesflow_statusid = 10 RETURN END

    SELECT mainstatuses_name, 1
    FROM MainStatusesTable
    WHERE mainstatuses_id = 10
```

Again if I remove the middle part then it works.

Rest of the stored procs are working absolutely fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may have to do with multiple recordsets and how the driver handles sending them (or how it may potentially handle it.)

Could you try to change one of your stored proc's to this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetColumns_Information]
@GroupOverride midsys_boolean AS
IF ( @GroupOverride = 1 )
BEGIN 
SELECT columns_id, columns_columntypesid, columns_columnname,    
columns_usercolumnname, 1 AS 'columns_columnsettings'
FROM ColumnsTable 
ORDER BY columns_id
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT columns_id, columns_columntypesid, columns_columnname,         
columns_usercolumnname, columns_columnsettings
FROM ColumnsTable
ORDER BY columns_id
END
```

In this case, you could simplify to one recordset

```
SELECT columns_id, columns_columntypesid, columns_columnname,    
columns_usercolumnname,
CASE
WHEN @GroupOverride = 1 THEN 1
ELSE columns_columnsettings
END AS 'columns_columnsettings'
FROM ColumnsTable 
ORDER BY columns_id
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

just simple add at the start:

```
set nocount on;
```

And at the end:

```
set nocount off;
```

And it will give you the result.

It occurs when we use any `if-else conditions`.

When you face such a condition that stored procedures give results in sql profiler, but are not showing any result in query fired from cakephp, then simply put `nocount on off` at the beginning and end respectively.